# where is review.save()[ place order ] related code is present

Tags: orders, checkout

I want to know how its redirecting to payment methods after we click on "place order" button

i can see "place order" button file here :

frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml

this is the code :

http://pastebin.com/auZAQJWZ

i want to know where is "review.save()" is present in magento folder path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method comes from the `opcheckout.js` file [`skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/opcheckout.js`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js#L918)